# MySQL UPDATE error to line 2

Tags: mysql

I have this script:

```
include ('connect.php');
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id='2'") ;
$da = mysql_fetch_array($data);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['project_name'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $curr = $_POST['curr'];
    $spec = $_POST['spec'];
     $sql = "UPDATE projects
            SET (name='$name', date='$date', amount='$amount', currency='$curr', specifications='$spec')
            WHERE id=2";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
 if($res)
        {
            echo "Upadate Successfull!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Sorry!";
            echo mysql_error($connect)."<br />";
echo error_reporting(E_ALL)."<br />";
echo ini_set('desplay_errors','1');
        }
```

NOTE: The connect.php file is working ok since I've used it before on other scripts but on the same server.

Every time I try to submit the form:
`Sorry!You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(name='sdadas', date='08/21/2013', amount='2444', currency='dollars', specificat' at line 2
32767`

What could be the problem?

Comment: Take the parens out of your update query

Comment: Could you echo the `$sql` and also tell us the datatype of column date ?

Comment: `UPDATE projects SET (name='myproject', date='08/21/2013', amount='2444', currency='dollars', specifications='None') WHERE id=2`

This is what I get.
Date is text.

Comment: If you *insist* on just slapping queries together using string concatenation, you will end up with all kinds of problems. Please, stop doing it this way. You will get burned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UPDATE .. SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) syntax does not use parenthesis:

```
UPDATE projects 
   SET name='myproject', date='08/21/2013', amount='2444', currency='dollars', specifications='None'
   WHERE id=2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the same query without the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the problem is that you have quotes around amount when you seem to be inputting an int.

Comment: Every data's type is text in my database, except the ID.